# Cравнение строк

Tags: java, scanner

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Hello" == s);
```

C клавиатуры вводится "Hello", по почему-то выдает false,хотя вроде бы строки равны

Comment: [Строки надо сравнивать не через `==`, а через `.equals()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+do+i+need+to+use+equals+java&oq=why+do+i+need+to+use+equals+java&aqs=chrome..69i57.3560j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

```
s.equals("joe")
```

`==` сравнивает ссылки на объекты